# Как отобразить гистограмму для данных из тепловой карты

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Нужно в виде гистограммы отобразить количество ненулевых ячеек в каждом столбце `heatmap(r)` при этом

1. В гистограмме три столбца с наибольшей частотой заполненных ячеек должны быть выделены красным цветом, все остальные синим цветом.
2. Гистограммы должна располагаться над тепловой картой, и отображение значений для оси - Х должны сохраниться.

Как это можно реализовать ?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(rc={'figure.facecolor':'white'})

columns = ['c1','c2','c3','c4']
d = [[1,2,10,11],[2,8,11,16],[7,8,10,15],[3,5,13,14],[10,11,12,13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=columns)
maxValue = df.values.max()

r = (df
     .stack()
     .reset_index(name="col")
     .assign(x=1)
     .pivot_table(index="level_0", columns="col", values="x")
     .reindex(range(1,maxValue+1), axis=1)
     .fillna(0)
     .astype("int8")
     .rename_axis(None)
     .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print(r)


print(r.sum(axis=0)) #Отобразить в виде histogram над heatmap

sns.heatmap(r, cmap="Blues", cbar=False, square = True, linewidths=1, linecolor="k")
plt.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labeltop=True)
#sns.histplot(r)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужна гистограмма, а не столбчатая диаграмма?

Comment: Можно и столбчатую диаграмму использовать.

Answer (score 4):

Решение без 1 пункта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(rc={'figure.facecolor':'white'})

columns = ['c1','c2','c3','c4']
d = [[1,2,10,11],
     [2,8,11,16],
     [7,8,10,15],
     [3,5,13,14],
     [10,11,12,13]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=columns)
maxValue = df.values.max()

r = (df
     .stack()
     .reset_index(name="col")
     .assign(x=1)
     .pivot_table(index="level_0", columns="col", values="x")
     .reindex(range(1,maxValue+1), axis=1)
     .fillna(0)
     .astype("int8")
     .rename_axis(None)
     .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1) # две строки одна колонка
arr = np.array(r.sum(axis = 0)) 
lenD = len(d) # количество строк в гистограмме
# подготовка массива для гистограммы
hist = [np.flatnonzero((arr - (lenD - i - 1)).clip(0, maxValue)) for i in  range(lenD)]

dfHist = pd.DataFrame(hist)
rHist = (dfHist
     .stack()
     .reset_index(name="col")
     .assign(x=1)
     .pivot_table(index="level_0", columns="col", values="x")
     .reindex(range(lenD), axis=0)
     .reindex(range(maxValue), axis=1)
     .fillna(0)
     .astype("int8")
     .rename_axis(None)
     .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

sns.heatmap(rHist, cmap="Blues", cbar=False, square = True, linewidths=1, linecolor="k", ax=ax[0])
sns.heatmap(r, cmap="Blues", cbar=False, square = True, linewidths=1, linecolor="k", ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

Ниже вариант с изменениями для ручной расскраски столбцов
можно его вынести в функцию
[image: вариант2]

```
for i in range(lenD):
     rHist[9][i] -= 0.6 if rHist[9][i]==1 else 0
     rHist[10][i] -= 0.6 if rHist[10][i]==1 else 0
     rHist[1][i] -= 0.6 if rHist[1][i]==1 else 0
   

sns.heatmap(rHist, cmap=sns.color_palette("tab10", 8), cbar=False, square = True, linewidths=1, linecolor="k", ax=ax[0])
```

Если поиграть с маской будет еще лучше
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
for i in range(lenD):
     rHist[9][i] -= 0.2 if rHist[9][i]==1 else 0
     rHist[10][i] -= 0.2 if rHist[10][i]==1 else 0
     rHist[1][i] -= 0.2 if rHist[1][i]==1 else 0
   

sns.heatmap(rHist, cmap=sns.color_palette("hls", 2), mask=(rHist==0), cbar=False, square = True, linewidths=1, linecolor="k", ax=ax[0])
```

Comment: а технически возможно реализовать 1) пункт ?

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, думаю, да (как минимум оттеннками), но если честно я не совсем понял даже какие столбцы подстветить самые высокие или самые частые

Comment: самые высокие. Идея - увидеть в матрице столбцы, которые содержат наибольшее число заполненных ячеек. И увидеть на сколько отличается плотность заполнения от соседних столцбов. Помимо этого хотелось на конкретном примере понять как с помощью библиотеки seaborn можно реализовать это на уровне отображения дополнительного графика для оси Х.,

Comment: @YuriyTigiev если честно я с seaborn не работал, разобрался походу чисто для Вас - сделал все что мог)

Comment: идея была такая если нужно сохранить четкое соответсвие по х двух графиков то нужно использовать один и тот же - чтобы не поплыли размеры, поэтому такая реализация